# Remove duplicate on the basis of attribute value

Tags: javascript, filter

I want to remove duplicate array from the response on the basis of the attribute value. If the `attribute_value` data match with other array attribute value then other should be removed.

logic is very simple. check duplicate attribute_value in each array and remove duplicate array and return
In response. now you can see the attribute value = 1 is thrice
and attribute value = 2 is twice

How do i compare and remove whole array if I see attribute value duplicate?

I tried with filter method which seems not working. Please help.

```
for(var j=0; j<social_post_link.length; j++){
    newFilterarray = social_post_link[j].activity_attributes[0].attribute_value.filter(function(item, index) {
      if (social_post_link[j].activity_attributes[0].attribute_value.indexOf(item) == index){
        return social_post_link;
      }
    });                                             
}
```

code

```
[
  {
    "id": "484822",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868117",
        "activity_id": "484822",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484884",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868175",
        "activity_id": "484884",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484888",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868182",
        "activity_id": "484888",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484823",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868120",
        "activity_id": "484823",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484975",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868344",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484891",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868189",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "3",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484903",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868200",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "4",
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Desired output

```
    [
  {
    "id": "484822",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868117",
        "activity_id": "484822",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484823",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868120",
        "activity_id": "484823",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484891",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868189",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "3",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "484903",
    "activity_attributes": [
      {
        "id": "868200",
        "attribute_name": "position",
        "attribute_value": "4",
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please post the input data rather than an image, further, the desired output.

Comment: When using `filter()` function, just return a boolean value based on your filter condition. Looks like in your case, return `true` inside your `if` condition. Return `false` in the end.

Comment: @Ele removed image and updated with response result of initial array.

Comment: Please post the desired output to get a better understanding about what you're expecting.

Comment: I want to check the `attribute_value' of the first array 'activity_attributes'. If the value is duplicate then remove duplicate.

Comment: Against the first `attribute_value` of the others arrays? for example, `others.activity_attributes[0].attribute_value`

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to filter here `social_post_link[j].activity_attributes[0].attribute_value` isn't an array, so it's not clear why you are trying to filter that. Are you trying to filter `activity_attributes` for each entry in `social_post_link` (which I assume is the top level object)? Or are you trying to filter the top level?

Comment: Yes @Ele compare that attribute_value with other array and if match then remove that duplicate array and return filter one.

Comment: @MattBurland i am trying to filter whole array by comparing attribute value. If the attribute value is duplicate comparing with other array then it should pop out the duplicate array and return.

Comment: @Santosh: That doesn't really answer the question. You have an array, each item in that array contains an array too (`activity_attributes`) which one are you trying to filter?

Comment: Your question would also be a _lot_ easier to look at if you removed all the unnecessary properties

Comment: `social_post_link[j].activity_attributes[0].attribute_value` I want to compare this value with each array. There are total 7 arrays in the response.

Comment: So what do you expect to have at the end? An array of `activity_attributes`? Or something else? As @Ele suggested, this would be a lot easier to understand if you included *what you expect to get at the end*. Otherwise we're just guessing. And wasting your time and ours. Help us to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167368/discussion-between-santosh-and-matt-burland).

Comment: Please come in chat.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use the `sortedUniqBy` function from *lodash*:

```js
const value = [{
    "id": "484822",
    "activity_attributes": [{
      "id": "868117",
      "activity_id": "484822",
      "attribute_name": "position",
      "attribute_value": "1",
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "484884",
    "activity_attributes": [{
      "id": "868175",
      "activity_id": "484884",
      "attribute_name": "position",
      "attribute_value": "1",
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "484888",
    "activity_attributes": [{
      "id": "868182",
      "activity_id": "484888",
      "attribute_name": "position",
      "attribute_value": "1",
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "484823",
    "activity_attributes": [{
      "id": "868120",
      "activity_id": "484823",
      "attribute_name": "position",
      "attribute_value": "2",
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "484975",
    "activity_attributes": [{
      "id": "868344",
      "attribute_name": "position",
      "attribute_value": "2",
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "484891",
    "activity_attributes": [{
      "id": "868189",
      "attribute_name": "position",
      "attribute_value": "3",
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "484903",
    "activity_attributes": [{
      "id": "868200",
      "attribute_name": "position",
      "attribute_value": "4",
    }, ]
  }
];

const result = _.sortedUniqBy(value, function(item) {
  return item.activity_attributes[0].attribute_value;
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```